# columnNames visible left side of the table instead of TOP

Tags: java, swing, jtable

```
try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:oradsn","mahesh","genius");

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from std");
    rs.next();
    int maxno= Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));
    String[] ColumnNames = {"Roll No","Name","English","Maths","Computer"};
    Object[][] rowdata=new Object[maxno][5]; 
    Statement stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1= stmt1.executeQuery("select * from std");
    int r=0;
    while(rs1.next()) {
        rowdata[r][0]=rs1.getString(1);
        rowdata[r][1]=rs1.getString(2);
        rowdata[r][2]=rs1.getString(3);
        rowdata[r][3]=rs1.getString(4);
        rowdata[r][4]=rs1.getString(5);
        r++;
    }
    JTable table = new JTable(rowdata,ColumnNames);
    jPanel1.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    jPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jPanel1.add(new JScrollPane().add(table));
    this.pack();
}
```

In this code I want `ColumnNames` to be on top of the table. but when I run program I have got `ColumnNames` left side and table on the right side.
I think the problem is in last 5 lines. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
jPanel1.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

then change

```
jPanel1.add(new JScrollPane().add(table));
```

to

```
jPanel1.add(new JScrollPane(table));
```

I probably also change

```
jPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

to

```
jPanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Also remember, a container has a single layout manager, if you change it, it WILL have an effect on the other components which were added to it before hand

I'd encourage you to have a look at [How to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) as they provide more information about how to work with them

Comment: OMG. You are a STAR. Thanks for the help.